# Wireless not connecting on Ubuntu 13.10, Toshiba Satellite pro L 650

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom, 13.10, toshiba-satellite

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Toshiba Satellite Pro L650. After several reboots, installing/ uninstalling the broadcom driver  I still can't connect.

It detects the wi fi signals and the icon flashes as if it's trying to connect but never actually does.

I'm really  quite rubbish with code and stuff, but I really like Ubuntu as an OS and would really appreciate any suggestions anyone can offer!

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v1.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: I also have this problem with a BCM4313.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

if there are any errors please continue with the commands then reboot. If you have not installed any other drivers but the wl driver then your wireless should be working.

Comment: @user2348639 you need to post your own question with information about your wifi card.